# Help identifying and finding shematics/datasheets for circuit board

Tags: pcb, identification, datasheet

Does someone know what kind of circuit board this is?

(Click to zoom)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I found it in an old cardboard box in the basement yesterday. "Sung Wei 08V0-A" is written at the top.

Where can I find schematics, datasheets or technical information about this product?

Comment: It's a single layer board, so shouldn't be that hards to trace the circuit.  However, I see little point in that.  The chip in the middle with the tiny bullet holes in it is almost certainly proprietary.  At best you can salvage a few parts if your time is worth nothing, but you don't need to know the circuit for that.

Comment: Just to make sure: you do know it's an optical PC mouse, right? The chip in the middle that Olin mentioned is an optical sensor.

Comment: Your hyperlinks appear to be broken.

Comment: @Madmanguruman They seem OK to me?

Comment: I was getting only a page with "Kommentarer - Rapportér bilde. Husk å inkludere adressen til bildet." and no images. Oh well, YMMV

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having taken apart a lot of PC mice, I can tell you with confidence that that's a [optical PC mouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_mouse) circuit board. Take a look at [all these other mouse PCBs](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44990110,d.d2k&biw=1366&bih=679&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=6GtkUea3K8nRsgaftYG4DQ&q=optical%20mouse#um=1&hl=en&safe=off&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=optical+mouse+inside&oq=optical+mouse+inside&gs_l=img.3..0.6511.7672.0.7817.6.6.0.0.0.0.96.418.6.6.0.crnk_rqr..0.0...1.1.8.img.12XgR4T-Zh4&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=9466abc2e4f8ab43&biw=1366&bih=679); you can see how similar in construction they all are.

The chip in the middle is an optical sensor. I googled it for its datasheet ("S5008"), but couldn't find any. Instead, some results hinted that the chip is a clone of the [Avago ADNS-5000 optical mouse sensor](http://www.avagotech.com/pages/en/navigation_interface_devices/navigation_sensors/led-based_sensors/adns-5000/) (datasheet [here](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV02-1006EN); must be downloaded).

The image of the chip in the datasheet looks exactly like the chip on your circuit board:

[image] [image]

As for a schematic, you can have a look at the application circuits in the datasheet of the chip, under *Typical applications*. That's the closest you can get to the actual schematic of your PCB, unless you do some reverse engineering yourself:

[image]

---

Further reading:

- [White Paper - Optical Mice and How They Work (409 KB,PDF)](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV02-1649EN)
- [Design Guide - ADNK-5003, Optical Mouse Designers Kit (269
  KB,PDF)](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV02-1139EN)